Сортировка массива только выбранных элементов
Задача заключается в том, чтобы отсортировать массив конкретных элементов, не затрагивая при этом позиции других элементов.
Что-то на подобии этого вопроса.
И так имеется массив storage.
[
    0:{ "Match": "fghfghfgh", "UUID": "a2e0b517-97d6-4050-bcd1-a0dc43a0b276" },
    1:{ "Match": "fghfghfghhhhh", "UUID": "57f03e08-9287-49ba-be4a-d59fa9c4e71c" },
    2:{ "Match": "Попадает под выборку 1", "UUID": "207036a0-48c9-4676-aa21-705a6b7d033a" },
    3:{ "Match": "asdasdasdasd", "UUID": "b448c73d-0232-4a6f-9935-7507afd3fb15" },
    4:{ "Match": "Попадает под выборку 2", "UUID": "bb9af394-0ab0-44f8-9488-a1ecbb10be75" },
    5:{ "Match": "Попадает под выборку 3", "UUID": "ef519c5c-83b8-4fb8-996b-de881a9123dd" },
    6:{ "Match": "5555", "UUID": "e089ce64-2774-49b1-ade9-ddc185bf9236" },
    7:{ "Match": "Попадает под выборку 4", "UUID": "ba789aab-2eee-4ae9-8fed-d571f76ab2fd" }
]

Каждый элемент имеет уникальное значение UUID, а по Match производится выборка элементов (2,4,5,7) и загрузка их в DOM
<div id="Selections">
    <div uuid="207036a0-48c9-4676-aa21-705a6b7d033a"></div>//storage[2] - 1
    <div uuid="bb9af394-0ab0-44f8-9488-a1ecbb10be75"></div>//storage[4] - 2
    <div uuid="ef519c5c-83b8-4fb8-996b-de881a9123dd"></div>//storage[5] - 3
    <div uuid="ba789aab-2eee-4ae9-8fed-d571f76ab2fd"></div>//storage[7] - 4
</div>

После манипуляций с DOM (dragstart/dragover/dragend) положение их поменялось.
<div id="Selections">
    <div uuid="207036a0-48c9-4676-aa21-705a6b7d033a"></div>// - 1
    <div uuid="ba789aab-2eee-4ae9-8fed-d571f76ab2fd"></div>// - 4
    <div uuid="bb9af394-0ab0-44f8-9488-a1ecbb10be75"></div>// - 2
    <div uuid="ef519c5c-83b8-4fb8-996b-de881a9123dd"></div>// - 3
</div>

В результате массив должен стать таким:
[
    0:{ "Match": "fghfghfgh", "UUID": "a2e0b517-97d6-4050-bcd1-a0dc43a0b276" },
    1:{ "Match": "fghfghfghhhhh", "UUID": "57f03e08-9287-49ba-be4a-d59fa9c4e71c" },
    2:{ "Match": "Попадает под выборку 1", "UUID": "207036a0-48c9-4676-aa21-705a6b7d033a" },
    3:{ "Match": "asdasdasdasd", "UUID": "b448c73d-0232-4a6f-9935-7507afd3fb15" },
    4:{ "Match": "Попадает под выборку 4", "UUID": "ba789aab-2eee-4ae9-8fed-d571f76ab2fd" },
    5:{ "Match": "Попадает под выборку 2", "UUID": "bb9af394-0ab0-44f8-9488-a1ecbb10be75" },
    6:{ "Match": "5555", "UUID": "e089ce64-2774-49b1-ade9-ddc185bf9236" },
    7:{ "Match": "Попадает под выборку 3", "UUID": "ef519c5c-83b8-4fb8-996b-de881a9123dd" }
]

Как видно элементы 0,1,3,6, которые не попали в выборку остались на своих местах, а выбранные поменялись местами согласно их новому положению из DOM.
Единственным решением, что пришло в голову:
let uuids = Array.prototype.map.call(Selections.children, i => i.getAttribute("uuid"));// Получаем массив uuid`ов из DOM в соответствии с их положением
let storage = await Storage.getValue("Includes");// Получаем наш массив storage

let newArray = new Array(storage.length);//Создаём новый массив равный storage для сортировки
let i = 0;//Переменная соответствующая положению элемента
storage.forEach((v, k) => {//Перебираем наш массив
    if (uuids.includes(v.UUID)) {//Если элемент имеется в нашей выборке
        newArray[k] = storage.find(e => e.UUID == uuids[i]);//Ищет элемент в исходном массиве и задаёт ему новую позицию в соответствии сортировки uuids
        i++;//Переходим к следующему элементу выборки
    } else {
        newArray[k] = v;// Оставляем элемент на прежнем месте
    }
});

await Storage.setValue("Includes", newArray);//Сохраняем массив

Может кто-то сталкивался с данной задачей, есть ли более деликатное решение?

Как вариант - запомни с каких мест ты их брал и заполни те места элементами в нужном порядке...

Если всё была так просто, значения в массиве могут меняться (удалятся - а значит смещаться и тогда будет бесполезно хранить индексы) в другом месте кода, собственно для этого и использую UUID чтобы их потом можно было найти

Поскольку речь зашла о реализации близкой к реальности, то отдельным комментарием:


let storage = [
  { Match: "fghfghfgh", UUID: "a2e0b517-97d6-4050-bcd1-a0dc43a0b276" },
  { Match: "fghfghfghhhhh", UUID: "57f03e08-9287-49ba-be4a-d59fa9c4e71c" },
  { Match: "Попадает под выборку 1", UUID: "207036a0-48c9-4676-aa21-705a6b7d033a", },
  { Match: "asdasdasdasd", UUID: "b448c73d-0232-4a6f-9935-7507afd3fb15", },
  { Match: "Попадает под выборку 2", UUID: "bb9af394-0ab0-44f8-9488-a1ecbb10be75", },
  { Match: "Попадает под выборку 3", UUID: "ef519c5c-83b8-4fb8-996b-de881a9123dd", },
  { Match: "5555", UUID: "e089ce64-2774-49b1-ade9-ddc185bf9236" },
  { Match: "Попадает под выборку 4", UUID: "ba789aab-2eee-4ae9-8fed-d571f76ab2fd", },
];

const UUIDs = [
  '207036a0-48c9-4676-aa21-705a6b7d033a',
  'bb9af394-0ab0-44f8-9488-a1ecbb10be75',
  'ef519c5c-83b8-4fb8-996b-de881a9123dd',
  'ba789aab-2eee-4ae9-8fed-d571f76ab2fd'
];

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const Selections = document.getElementById("Selections");
  const selection = storage.reduce((acc, val, index) => {
    if(UUIDs.includes(val.UUID)) {
      acc[index] = val;
      let div = document.createElement("div");
      div.textContent = val.Match;
      div.dataset.index = index;
      div.setAttribute("uuid", val.UUID);
      div.setAttribute("draggable", true);
      Selections.appendChild(div);
    }
    return acc;  
  }, {});
})

function DragAndDrop(id) {
  const wrapper = document.getElementById(id);
  wrapper.addEventListener('dragstart', (e) => {
    this.root = id;
    this.target = e.target;
    e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
    e.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', e.target.outerHTML);
    e.target.style.opacity = '0.2'; 
  });
  wrapper.addEventListener('dragleave', (e) => {
    if (this.root && e.target.draggable) {
      e.target.closest('[data-index]')?.classList.remove('over'); 
    }
  });
  wrapper.addEventListener('dragover', (e) => {
    if (this.root) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move';
    }
  });
  wrapper.addEventListener('dragenter', (e) => {
    if (this.root) {
      e.target.closest('[data-index]')?.classList.add('over');
    }
  });
  wrapper.addEventListener('dragend', (e) => {
    delete this.root;
    e.target.removeAttribute('style');
  });
  wrapper.addEventListener('drop', (e) => {
    if (this.root && this.target !== e.target && e.target.dataset.index) {

      // получаем текущие индексы и меняем из местами в storage
      const x = this.target.dataset.index;
      const y = e.target.dataset.index;
      [storage[x], storage[y]] = [storage[y], storage[x]];

      e.target.dataset.index = x; //+ меняем индекс у замещаемого на текущий

      e.preventDefault();
      e.target.closest('[data-index]')?.classList.remove('over'); 
      delete this.root;
      this.target.outerHTML = e.target.outerHTML;
      e.target.outerHTML = e.dataTransfer.getData('text/html');

      const current = Selections.querySelector(`[uuid="${this.target.getAttribute('uuid')}"]`);
      current.dataset.index = y; // меняем индекс у перетаскиваемого на текущий

    }
  });
}
const all = new DragAndDrop('Selections');


view.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.clear();
  console.log('storage', storage);
}, false);
div#Selections>div[index]{
  opacity: 0.2;
}
#Selections {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 1px;
}
#Selections div {
  background-color: green; 
  line-height: 32px;
  padding: 0 8px;
}

.over {
  border: solid 1px black;
}
<div id="Selections"></div>
<br><input type="button" id="view" value="View">



Дополнение согласно реального кода.
Подход к неизвестному числу параметров в присваивании реализован при помощи new Function();


let storage = [
  { Match: "fghfghfgh", UUID: "a2e0b517-97d6-4050-bcd1-a0dc43a0b276" },
  { Match: "fghfghfghhhhh", UUID: "57f03e08-9287-49ba-be4a-d59fa9c4e71c" },
  { Match: "Попадает под выборку 1", UUID: "207036a0-48c9-4676-aa21-705a6b7d033a"},
  { Match: "asdasdasdasd", UUID: "b448c73d-0232-4a6f-9935-7507afd3fb15" },
  { Match: "Попадает под выборку 2", UUID: "bb9af394-0ab0-44f8-9488-a1ecbb10be75" },
  { Match: "Попадает под выборку 3", UUID: "ef519c5c-83b8-4fb8-996b-de881a9123dd" },
  { Match: "5555", UUID: "e089ce64-2774-49b1-ade9-ddc185bf9236" },
  { Match: "Попадает под выборку 4", UUID: "ba789aab-2eee-4ae9-8fed-d571f76ab2fd" },
]
const Selections = document.getElementById("Selections");

const UUIDs = [
  '207036a0-48c9-4676-aa21-705a6b7d033a',
  'bb9af394-0ab0-44f8-9488-a1ecbb10be75',
  'ef519c5c-83b8-4fb8-996b-de881a9123dd',
  'ba789aab-2eee-4ae9-8fed-d571f76ab2fd'
];

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const selection = storage.reduce((acc, val, index) => {
    if(UUIDs.includes(val.UUID)) {
      acc[index] = val;
      let div = document.createElement("div");
      div.textContent = val.Match;
      div.dataset.index = index;
      div.setAttribute("uuid", val.UUID);
      div.setAttribute("draggable", true);
      Selections.appendChild(div);
    }
    return acc;  
  }, {});
})

const getNextElement = (cursorPosition, currentElement) => {
  const currentElementCoord = currentElement.getBoundingClientRect()
  const currentElementCenter =
    currentElementCoord.y + currentElementCoord.height / 2
  const nextElement =
    cursorPosition < currentElementCenter
      ? currentElement
      : currentElement.nextElementSibling
  return nextElement
}

let rB; // порядок элементов "До".
Selections.addEventListener("dragstart", e => {
    let currentElement = e.target;
    currentElement.setAttribute("index", Position(currentElement));
    
    // собираем текущий индекс элементов
        let range = [...Selections.querySelectorAll('[data-index]')];
        rB = range.map(b => b.dataset.index);
    // console.log('rB', rB);
    
});

Selections.addEventListener("dragend", async e => {
    let currentElement = e.target;
    let index = {}

    index.Previous = parseInt(currentElement.getAttribute("index"));
    index.Current = Position(currentElement);
    currentElement.removeAttribute("index");

    if (index.Previous === index.Current) return;
    
    // rA порядок элементов "После".
    let range = [...Selections.querySelectorAll('[data-index]')];
        const rA = range.map(b => b.dataset.index);
    // console.log('rA', rA);
   
    const assignmentString = '['+rB.map(b => `storage[${b}]`)+']=['+rA.map(b => `storage[${b}]`)+']';
        const destructuringAssignment = new Function(assignmentString);
        destructuringAssignment();
        range.map((el,i) => el.dataset.index = rA[i]); // переиндексировать на текущие цифры
        console.log('storage', storage);

});

function Position(element) {
    return Array.prototype.indexOf.call(Selections.children, element);
}

Selections.addEventListener("dragover", async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const activeElement = Selections.querySelector("div[index]");//Selections.querySelector(`.selected`);
    let currentElement = e.target;
    if (currentElement?.parentElement?.parentElement == Selections) currentElement = currentElement.parentElement;
    //console.log(activeElement, currentElement);
    const isMoveable = activeElement !== currentElement;
    if (!isMoveable) return;
    const nextElement = getNextElement(e.clientY, currentElement);

    if (nextElement && activeElement === nextElement.previousElementSibling || activeElement === nextElement) return;

    Selections.insertBefore(activeElement, nextElement);
    //console.log(activeElement, nextElement);
});
div#Selections>div[index] {
    opacity: 0.2;
}
#Selections {
  background-color: green
}
<div id="Selections"></div>




я понимаю ваш замысел с деструктивным присвоением, но решение d-a-d у вас иное, оно меняет местами - поэтому реализация простая, а у меня смещает, т.е. элементы (1,2,3,4) перетаскивая (4) на (2) - станет (1,4,2,3) != (1,4,3,2) , а из-за изменчивого storage - отказался хранить индексы в DOM, поэтому использую UUID

@Rid вот блин... недосмотрел.) Повелся на реализацию, а не на факт. Просто в моём обычном представлении когда делают смещение элементов, то и визуализация несколько иная. Например как это реализовано в закладка браузера, ну или так.  Учёл ваш нюанс, позже вечером или ночью гляну что там нужно поменять у вас.

@Rid смотри Дополнение.

интересное решение, но не накладно будет если элементов будет не 4, а 20-40+?, Это что-то типа eval, но с доступом только к глобальным переменным.

@Rid что-то типа eval так и есть, просто более корректная и безопасная реализация. И, даже если их там будет пару сотен отработает мгновенно*,  и уж тем более если сравнивать с любым другим подходом к сортировке помимо деструктурирующего присваивания.  Думаю вам ничего не стоит проверить  на огромном объекте целиком.)

@Rid ну хоть закрыл вопрос,) однако, если хочешь, не стал вчера дописывать комментарий, дабы не сваливать всё в одну кучу (хотел было предложить тебе подумать ещё над одним вариантом сортировки без new Function(), а за счёт splice() и написать его самостоятельно).  Впрочем люблю головоломки и сам. Не знаю будет ли оно быстрее и насколько, но оставлю его в сыром виде здесь. Думаю с сутью разберётесь и обернёте в функцию, если есть желание.

Дабы упростить вашу жизнь :) давайте посмотрим на последовательность действий и оттолкнемся от неё. Не стану писать за вас весь код, и уж тем более перетаскивание элементов но подскажу идеальное решение согласно постановке задачи.

Вы делаете выборку по списку UUIDs и результат вносите в DOM, где при помощи draggable вручную меняете их последовательность. Я верно понимаю?
Значит всё что вам нужно чтобы упростить задачу — получить не только сами элементы, но и их индекс.

Смотрите.


const storage = [
  { "Match": "fghfghfgh", "UUID": "a2e0b517-97d6-4050-bcd1-a0dc43a0b276" },
  { "Match": "fghfghfghhhhh", "UUID": "57f03e08-9287-49ba-be4a-d59fa9c4e71c" },
  { "Match": "Попадает под выборку 1", "UUID": "207036a0-48c9-4676-aa21-705a6b7d033a" },
  { "Match": "asdasdasdasd", "UUID": "b448c73d-0232-4a6f-9935-7507afd3fb15" },
  { "Match": "Попадает под выборку 2", "UUID": "bb9af394-0ab0-44f8-9488-a1ecbb10be75" },
  { "Match": "Попадает под выборку 3", "UUID": "ef519c5c-83b8-4fb8-996b-de881a9123dd" },
  { "Match": "5555", "UUID": "e089ce64-2774-49b1-ade9-ddc185bf9236" },
  { "Match": "Попадает под выборку 4", "UUID": "ba789aab-2eee-4ae9-8fed-d571f76ab2fd" }
];

const UUIDs = ['207036a0-48c9-4676-aa21-705a6b7d033a', 'bb9af394-0ab0-44f8-9488-a1ecbb10be75', 'ef519c5c-83b8-4fb8-996b-de881a9123dd', 'ba789aab-2eee-4ae9-8fed-d571f76ab2fd'];

const selection = storage.reduce((acc, val, index) => {
  if(UUIDs.includes(val.UUID)) acc[index] = val;
  return acc    
}, {});

console.log( selection );




вы не поверите, но почти всё готово для упрощения. Всё что нам осталось это вывести элементы в DOM (draggable-контейнер), но с небольшим бонусом в виде атрибута data с тем самым index;



<div id="Selections">
    <div data-index="2" uuid="207036a0-48c9-4676-aa21-705a6b7d033a">storage[2]</div>
    <div data-index="4" uuid="bb9af394-0ab0-44f8-9488-a1ecbb10be75">storage[4]</div>
    <div data-index="5" uuid="ef519c5c-83b8-4fb8-996b-de881a9123dd">storage[5]</div>
    <div data-index="7" uuid="ba789aab-2eee-4ae9-8fed-d571f76ab2fd">storage[7]</div>
</div>




Осталась лишь самая малость — на стадии drop получить dataset.index тех двух элементов, которые вы только что поменяли местами и внести изменения в storage через деструктурирующее присваивание (допустим это были 4 и 7 элементы):
[storage[4], storage[7]] = [storage[7], storage[4]];


И вуаля. Впрочем возможно вы захотите пойти пойти по своему пути и вносить сразу несколько изменений,.. деструктурирующее присваивание вам в помощь, если вы знаете их текущий индекс, то можете поменять местами все четыре одновременно.


const storage = [
    { "Match": "fghfghfgh", "UUID": "a2e0b517-97d6-4050-bcd1-a0dc43a0b276" },
    { "Match": "fghfghfghhhhh", "UUID": "57f03e08-9287-49ba-be4a-d59fa9c4e71c" },
    { "Match": "Попадает под выборку 1", "UUID": "207036a0-48c9-4676-aa21-705a6b7d033a" },
    { "Match": "asdasdasdasd", "UUID": "b448c73d-0232-4a6f-9935-7507afd3fb15" },
    { "Match": "Попадает под выборку 2", "UUID": "bb9af394-0ab0-44f8-9488-a1ecbb10be75" },
    { "Match": "Попадает под выборку 3", "UUID": "ef519c5c-83b8-4fb8-996b-de881a9123dd" },
    { "Match": "5555", "UUID": "e089ce64-2774-49b1-ade9-ddc185bf9236" },
    { "Match": "Попадает под выборку 4", "UUID": "ba789aab-2eee-4ae9-8fed-d571f76ab2fd" }
];
[storage[2], storage[4], storage[5], storage[7]] = [storage[2], storage[7], storage[4], storage[5]];
console.log( storage );




Если перетащить 4й элемент на место 2го, то это не значит, то они поменяются местами. Просто 4й станет вторым, второй третим, а третий переедет на 4ю строку. И вот тут как раз наступают сложности...

@SwaD вот я про это и говорю, что они не просто меняются местами, а меняют расположение относительно друг-друга согласно массиву содержащий их новый порядок.

@Rid Есть у меня одна мысль, надо потестить

@SwaD @Rid  во-первых я не демонстрировал готовый код, а лишь сам подход. Во-вторых это ничего не меняет. Мы знаем index элементов и этого достаточно. 4 и 7 поменялись местами и этого достаточно — [storage[4], storage[7]] = [storage[7], storage[4]] И оба эти аргумента мы можем получить прямо в drop. Если бы ТС добавил свою реализацию draggable я бы дописал готовое решение. Но... если хотите поспорить с реальностью кода уже существующего в моём проекте, то я готов.)

@SwaD и... возможно мы друг друга не так поняли, но по дефалту draggable работает несколько иначе чем привычный по-старинке drag-and-drop. В draggable элементы буквально меняются местами. И для того, чтобы написать привычные сдвиги нужно реально потрахаться. Суть в том, что ТС не представил свою реализацию. Что собственно никак не помещает снять новую последовательность элементов в виде массива (по кнопке Save) и поменять их в  storage для того и дописал финальный код с примером.

@stylok Со всем уважением говорю, писать за меня код не нужно, он уже есть (для тех кто не понял - "Единственным решением, что пришло в голову:....код"), и уж тем более не стал пихать сюда ещё и перетаскивание элемента... 1) Не по UUID, а по Match пример: /Попадает под выборку/.test(element.Math), но не суть 3) Я изначально хотел использовать деструктурирующее присваивание, но это не совсем то,  что нужно, тут вы явно присваиваете значения, т.к знаете их количество, но как поступить при переборе элементов?

@Rid я (мой код) не знает количества и знать не хочет он работает по их индексу (положению в массиве). Будь ваш массив на 100500 тысяч элементов и выборка в 100 этот код будет работать.

@stylok [storage[2], storage[4], storage[5], storage[7]] = [storage[2], storage[7], storage[4], storage[5]]; - а это что, а если их не 4, а 15 или 25?

@stylok вы может не так поняли, меня не (1) часть вашего кода интересует, а (3), там вы явно указываете что и куда переместить зная их количество

@Rid во-первых это дописка на случай если вы реализовали drag-and-drop со смещением элементов и кнопкой Savе и тем не менее я написал само присваивание а не код реализации, что не мешает сделать для этого функцию. ОДНАКО я остановился на том, что вам достаточно того чтобы вносить изменения на стадии двух элементов (их всегда два), если draggable реализован без смещения а по замене как-то так. Давненько писал тот код, так что то, что под рукой, а то из проекта тяжело выдернуть.

Пример

@SwaD с учётом имеющейся задачи, добавил более полноценную реализацию ниже. К слову в моём проекте сделано одновременно проще и сложнее за счёт того, что index-ы у меня не меняются местами поскольку они служат обёрткой примерно так <div data-index="42"><a id="17" draggable="true">x</a></div> Т.е. я перетаскиваю внутренние элементы, благодаря чему сами индексы остаются на своих местах.
